# Can't decode u00e9 in javadoc files

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, javadoc

I have an object named business_activity which has a display name "activité". From this object I create a class, something like this:

```
    @DisplayName("activité")
    public class business_activity extends business_element
{ ... }
```

I use a `PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(f), true, "UTF-8");` to write the class to the source files.

After this, I want to generate the javadoc for this class. The problem is, in the javadoc file, `activité` is displayed like this: `activitu00e9`.

The javadoc command that I run has the `-encoding`, `-docencoding` and `-charset` parameters set to UTF-8.

I tried also with other encodings and the output is still incorrect.
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!